# Getting Custom tokens from Android App in Firebase Auth

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-authentication

i am developing an application that requires firebase custom tokens.
I can assign custom claims by callable cloud functions in node.js server. Now i need them in my app for controlling access. How can i achieve it?

```
FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getTokens()
```

**like that**

I have tried to get tokens from firestore but it costs read operations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `getIdToken()` on Auth user to get claims.

Check out the below example:

```
user.getIdToken(false).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<GetTokenResult>() {
  @Override
  public void onSuccess(GetTokenResult result) {
    boolean isAdmin = result.getClaims().get("admin");
    if (isAdmin) {
      // Show admin UI.
      showAdminUI();
    } else {
      // Show regular user UI.
      showRegularUI();
    }
  }
});
```

Also please keep in mind that ID Token need to be refreshed before these are updated which you can do by following,

`currentUser.getIdToken(true)`

And custom claims are only to verify roles and for storing very small data. It should not be used to keep user's information.

Source and Further Read: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/custom-claims#propagate_custom_claims_to_the_client

Answer (score 1):

currentUser has getIdToken method with a callback argument addOnSuccessListener. The addOnSuccessListener give access to GetTokenResult(map) use that to check your claims.

```
private fun login() {
        val user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().currentUser
        if (user == null) showAuthActivity()
        user?.getIdToken(true) // forceRefresh: boolean Force refresh regardless of token expiration.
            ?.addOnSuccessListener {it: GetTokenResult ->
                val role = (it.claims["admin"] as? Boolean)
                    ?: (it.claims["clientUser"] as? Boolean) ?: false
                if (role) {
                    startActivity(Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java))
                    finish()
                } else {
                    showAuthActivity()
                    showToast("You don't have permissions to use this app")
                }
            }
            ?.addOnFailureListener {
                showAuthActivity()
                showToast("Something went wrong e = ${it.message}")
            }?.addOnCanceledListener {
                showAuthActivity()
            }
    }
```